# R anova (aov) repeated measures gives same effect in different error sources

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I have a repeated measures design, where A and B are within-subjects factors. I tried

```
m1 <- aov(y ~ A * B + Error(subject/(A*B)))
summary(m1)
```

But the results came back:

```
Error: subject
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
A          1 176166607 176166607   20.89 0.00600 **
B          1 143823233 143823233   17.05 0.00909 **
Residuals  5  42166494   8433299                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subject:A
      Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
A      1 2263122 2263122   4.404 0.0899 .
B      2 1056720  528360   1.028 0.4227  
Residuals  5 2569581  513916                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subject:B
              Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
B              3 2.531e+09 843650464  60.871 6.22e-10 ***
A:B            2 8.212e+07  41060723   2.963   0.0759 .  
Residuals 19 2.633e+08  13859601                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subject:A:B
          Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
A:B        3  2075177  691726   1.152  0.351
Residuals 21 12610432  600497               

Error: Within
           Df    Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 477 442259616  927169
```

Why is each effect showing up with so many error terms? Am I misunderstanding something? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Although asked in terms of R, this is really a question about understanding rmANOVA. I think it should be considered on-topic here

Comment: A complete answer should probably address your fundamental statistical question but you're also are doing something wrong. I don't think you have one measure of each variable for each subject. Try `table(A, B, subject)`. Every item should be 1. If it's not, fix that first and rerun and repost the results.

Comment: Thanks John! that was exactly what I wasn't understanding. I guess I had assumed that R was clever enough to aggregate for me, but I guess in hindsight there's nothing to indicate that it should.